Please help to solve this

At line:1 char:1
+ virtualenv kasun
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (virtualenv:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

I want to install correctly.

Have you tried using py -m venv kasun instead?

Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

The bad title probably attracts more downvotes than this would otherwise deserve. The title should reveal the topic of your question so that visitors can tell whether it’s within their area of expertise or interest.

I recommend you check your python version first python3 -v or python -v
Then pip install virtualenv
You need to configure your virtual env and python properly first before your activate the environment.
You can then check your virtualenv version with virtualenv -vand you should be able to start your venv with cd ing over to your directory and create a virtual env with virtualenv __your_dir_name__ then activate with ./venv/Scripts/activate
